# Parsing webpage with some html tags using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

For example:

```
content=Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)).at_css(".appwindow").text
```

This example parse text from .appwindow (only text).
How can I parse this text with `<p>` tag?

Comment: I don't understand the question, would you mind giving some example?

Comment: This question is missing enough information to be able to help. We need a URL for the content in question, or some sample HTML showing the

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to find either the full HTML of the first element that has an `appwindow` class, or perhaps the inner HTML. If so:

```
require 'nokogiri'
html = Nokogiri::HTML <<ENDHTML
  <div id='menu'>menu</div>
  <div class='appwindow'><p>Hello <b>World</b>!</p></div>
ENDHTML

puts html.at_css('.appwindow').text
#=> Hello World!

puts html.at_css('.appwindow').to_html
#=> <div class="appwindow"><p>Hello <b>World</b>!</p></div>

puts html.at_css('.appwindow').inner_html
#=> <p>Hello <b>World</b>!</p>
```

See the list of [methods on `Nokogiri::XML::Node`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#instance_methods) for other options available to you.